# How to safely shutdown a Play Framework app

Tags: playframework

I want to be sure that any request threads have finished their processing before my play app exits, so I have 2 questions:

1) What signal can I send to invoke the Global onStop method? I've used Ctrl-d running activator on the command line while developing, but when deployed, the app will be started and stopped by a script that wants to send a kill signal to stop it. I've tried different signals, but none have called onStop. Is there a way?

2) When onStop is called, I want to verify there are no request threads running and wait on any that are. What is the best way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the discussion on graceful shutdown at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1789

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process like so.

```
$ kill $(cat target/universal/stage/RUNNING_PID)
```

For more info check [How to kill a Play Framework process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829549/how-to-kill-a-play-framework-process).