# How to kill a Play Framework process?

Tags: scala, playframework, process

I closed the terminal window by mistake and I don't know the PID of the running Play process. How to find it? Or, where is the RUNNING_PID file?

I am using Play 2.4.6 and running in non-production mode (`activator run`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using dev mode (`activator run`), no `RUNNING_PID` file is generated. The process won't detach and will be killed when the terminal is closed.

By default the `RUNNING_PID` file is written to `./target/universal/stage/RUNNING_PID` (inside the project's root directory) when using production mode.

So, to kill the process (from the project directory), you can:

```
$ kill $(cat target/universal/stage/RUNNING_PID)
```

You can also change the [configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration#Changing-the-path-of-RUNNING_PID) variable `pidfile.path` to write the file to where ever you want, as long as the Play application has the correct write permissions.

For example:

```
pidfile.path=/var/run/play.pid
```

Or as a command line argument (for a staged binary):

```
$ target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dpidfile.path=/var/run/play.pid
```

Comment: in the target directory, I only have `native_libraries`, `resolution-cache`, `scala-2.11`, `streams` and `web`.. the command `find . RUNNING_PID` cannot find it either...

Comment: @ticofab What version of Play is this? And how are you running it in production mode?

Comment: I am using play 2.4.6. Not production mode - I'll update the question.

Comment: There is no `RUNNING_PID` file in dev mode (`activator run`). If you close the console, the process is destroyed. I assumed you were using production mode, since that is the only time the file is generated. There's no way to detach the process in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

I only want to add that there is a command comes with Activator (for Play 2.4+) which kill/stop process (in a kind of nice way).

```
Activator stopProd
```

Here is a screenshot of how it looks

[image]